Not great at regexs. Trying to code-golf this beast of a regex WITHOUT using string replacement (for G-Zip purposes)
Here it is:
^(?:(?:(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?::|\.|,))?(\d+)?(?::|\.|,))?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:(?:\.|:|,)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)?)?(?:,|,(?:(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?::|\.|,))?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?::|\.|,))?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:(?:\.|:|,)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)?)?$

What am I doing:
Matching any ranged timestamp (HH:MM:SS:MS,HH:MM:SS:MS) with a few "leniences"

Any length digits - we do NOT need restrictions to strict 24 hr, 59 min / sec, \d{1,9} milliseconds. I do automatic conversions for this and shift in my code allowing lenience
Likewise, I'm not strict on requiring the : as the delimiter. It can be one of:
: OR , OR . OR |
Similarly, they don't NEED to strictly put digits into any specific slot. They can be blank. :MM:SS:MS, HH::SS:MS, etc in all combinatorial possibilites
The start and end parts are OPTIONAL. Meaning r1,r2, r1, ,r2, r1, are all valid

I COULD do simple string replacement / injections given how markedly repetitive this is. In most langs G-Zip compresses better w/o this.
I need the capture group (HH:MM:SS:MS) for EACH range. I am mapping these from captured groups -> milliseconds conversion -> human readable time (e.g. - 4 hours, 15 minutes, 30 seconds, 4234 milliseconds, 300 nanoseconds, ...). So, eight for r1, r2.
Language: JavaScript
Update: Per the comments in the answer it is actually more simplistic and flexible to do the below:
 t.split','.map(x=>x.split(/[:|;-]/).reverse().reduce((p,c,i)=>p*1+60**i*(c*1||0))*1e3)

For the millisecond range conversion I was after vs 8 capturing groups. Regex was really the wrong choice here. But, nonetheless it was a good discussion surrounding capturing groups and efficacy.
This assumes: HH:MM:SS format with milli as -> HH:MM:SS.MS

Welcome to Code Golf! Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you replace (?::|\.|,) with [:.,]? Also, make sure to mention what flavor of regex this is, since some support more advanced features and others don't

Ah, yeah I could. That's a good point. It's JavaScript so no fancy PERL usages if I'm not mistaken. Will update post.

what's wrong with smth like (\d*[:,.|]){3}\d*? do you need to capture each individually?

You might also want to mention what, if anything, you want in the capture groups

@guest4308 Indeed. I am re-mapping them to human-readable strings so each group is important to know for conversion to millisecodns -> human readable time

@emanresuA Done. Good point.

regex, 40 bytes
^(\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)$
try it online!
or if you'll allow all the delimers to be exactly the same, this is even better:
regex, 34 bytes
^(\d*)([:|,.])(\d*)\2(\d*)\2(\d*)$
try it online!
lessons that can be learned:
in general, regex tends to be simpler than you think it is. often, if you're thinking of including a non-capturing group, it's easier to just get rid of the group altogether; non-capturing groups don't increase the 'power' of a regex at all (ie, there is no pattern a non-capturing group lets you capture that you couldn't have already matched without it).
also, you should only use | alternation for exact strings; [] character classes are much easier to use for individual characters. additionally, alternation can be very slow in terms of big-O if you have * or + counts on the individual elements.
finally, if you're using ? for a group, rethink about why you want that group in the first place. it's often easier to read a regex with less groups where each element has its count directly following it and allowing groups to match without a specified count.

Yep. that was my mistake. For some reason I totally forgot I could use a wildcard * for optional captures. I was thinking I had to force everything into a (?:(regex))? block for some reason which led to all of the nesting.
Since I need the range (start, end) I transformed your regex to:
^(\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)(?:,(\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*))?$
In order to capture all eight groups (HH:MM:SS.MS, HH:MM:SS.MS)

@Overflow2341313 ah, I thought you were asking for a timestamp in a range rather than a range defined by two timestamps. anyways, you just did the same thing again with non-capturing groups at the very end there. what you likely want instead is ^(\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*),(\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)[:|,.](\d*)$ (unless the second time is optional?)

Yes. Either part of the range is optional.
So, valid formats could be:
r1,r2, ,r2, r1, r1 with only one being determined as range 1 vacuously per no determiner which makes sense for media (you seek forwards not back typically) @guest4308 I am  still working on tweaking making both optional. I think I need to wrap both honestly. I think that was my lapse in the psot. I glossed over this in the combinatorial possibilities. People generally tend to mess up formats, so leniency (within reason) is desirable.

yeah, using what you first commented with some ()? 0/1 group around the first section would get you those formats. 8 groups is a lot for a regex; it would likely be better if you use str.split(/[:|,.]/);  and then check if it can becomes an int array of the right length

Yep. That's the ticket. Simply really is better than complex sometimes AND doing it this way is a lot more flexible. t.split','.map(x=>x.split(/[:|;-]/).reverse().reduce((p,c,i)=>p*1+60**i*(c*1||0))*1e3) Is a flexible one liner that allows errors in ANY slot for millisecond conversion. Which, ironically, is shorter than my original regex and almost as short as the revamped versions above. The ' in the split are supposed to be bacticks for this to work (no parens) but can't nest ticks in code formatting
